# Why lasso can make feature selection but ridge method not?

Tags: regression, regularized

Can anyone explain me why with L1 penalty(Lasso) some variables weights can be 0 but with ridge method can never be 0?

I know that lasso uses absolute value penalization and ridge squared value, but i don't understand why when you solve the equation this can happen.

Regards